# Bookmark facebook app with parameter

Tags: php, facebook

I'd like my app users to be able to bookmark my app with some additional parameter (for instance: http://apps.facebook.com/my-app/?ref=bookmarks&additional=aaaa) depending on which I will present my users different output. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. You have to use the `app_data` parameter. Have a lookt at these links:

- [Facebook documentation Signed Request](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/)
- [Facebook iFrame Tab Applications](http://acknowledgement.co.uk/post/First-Look-Tutorial-Facebook-iFrame-Tab-Applications/244)

So, basically, the app_data parameter will be passed through in the `signed_request` to your app within the iFrame. For this to work you have to json_encode the parameter. So, in your example case:

```
http://apps.facebook.com/my-app/?app_data={'ref': 'bookmarks', 'additional': 'aaaa'}
```

and finally url encoded:

```
http://apps.facebook.com/my-app/?app_data=7B%27ref%27%3A+%27bookmarks%27%2C+%27additional%27%3A+%27aaaa%27%7D
```

to gain access, you have to read out the signed_request:

```
$app_data = json_decode($signed_request["app_data"]);
$additional = $app_data['additional'];
```

Comment: I'm under impression that you didn't entirely understand my problem. Or maybe I don't entirely understand your answer :). I'm talking about bookmarking my app, like when clicking <fb:bookmark /> button - using it adds my app to user's left panel, but with its base address, and no additional parameters. My question is: how do I pass additional params to the bookmark action?

Comment: well...honestly I don't know how to change the parameters for the bookmarks. my answer just explains how to receive additional parameters in your app. once you know how to change the bookmark url, you know how to deal with the additional data :)

Comment: Yeah, I know that and was hoping you could help me understand how to change bookmark url :P. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

fb:bookmark is part of the deprecated FBML, so long term you need to look for a different solution anyway